# Call of member function of objects in arrays

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

Given the following classes:

```
class animal {
public:
    virtual void noise() { };
};

class cat: public animal{
public:
    void noise() {
        cout << "mew" << endl;
    }
};
```

Why does this work (prints the correct noise):

```
animal *animals[2];
animals[0] = new dog;
animals[0]->noise();
```

But this doesn't:

```
animal animals[2];
dog dog1;
animals[0] = dog1;
animals[0].noise();
```

Is there a way to make it work without using pointers? 
The software wants me to add more text but I think I have already made my question very clear so this is just random text...

Comment: Your real mistake is that the non-leaf base class is not abstract, as it better had be.

Comment: It has not become clear, hence me asking the question.

Comment: Which of those two results surprises you? And *why* do you want to make it work without pointers?

Comment: The second one not working surprises me. Because using new is to be avoided I was told. + out out sheer curiosity.